# Android charging behavior when in use

Tags: android, usb, battery

I'm working on a hardware/firmware/Android app project where the Android (in this case a Nexus 7 tablet) connects to a custom hardware platform via USB. The Android is in Accessory mode, which means the other end of the wire (the Host) supplies power to the Android. The hardware has a dedicated 5V 2A switching supply for the USB connector so there is plenty of current available for the tablet.

When the Android is plugged in to the hardware, it reports that the battery is charging and it requests 500mA from the USB connection (for those who don't know, the USB protocol requires the device to inform the host of its current requirements). The hardware easily provides this current and the 5V stays rock-solid.

Despite this, the charge level never changes as long as the device remains in use. This application uses the tablet in what is basically a kiosk mode - the display stays on at full brightness continuously. Sleep the tablet and the battery charges, but leave it on and there is no reported change in the battery level.

The only explanation I can think of is that the Android's power supply circuitry cannot simultaneously handle the current requirements of both full operation and battery charging. But I wonder if this is a conscious decision based on expected power availability, and if there may be some sort of configuration option in the OS that would inform the OS that more current is, indeed, available. Perhaps then the OS would request more current from the Host and have enough to both charge the battery and run the device at the same time.

Anyone have any data on this? Thanks!

Comment: I notice that the AC adapter that came with the tablet is 5V @ 2A, so apparently they believe it needs two amps. Yet the tablet only requests 500mA when connected. I'm hoping this is a configurable parameter - might only be accessible programmatically, which would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

When I started a company that designed battery chargers for cell phones and the like, I didn't realize that it took more than providing a voltage source to a USB connector.  At first we encountered having to provide different voltages on the data pins to tell the connected device how much current it could expect to draw. Now there are several manufacturers of USB interface ICs that do all the dirty work of handshaking and act as current limiters as well.  Most smartphones today draw an average of 1A from the 5V USB bus. Some can, and will (especially Apple products) draw up to 2.1A if allowed.  Most tablets run in the range of 1.5A to 2.1A.  Any of the above will run in a mode drawing lesser current, if the device finds the charger unable to supply the full current. This will sometimes, as in your case, allow the device to either run or charge, but not both.  In some cases, the available current isn't enough to maintain a charge level , and the device's battery slowly discharges, even though it's connected to a charger. If you Google "USB charger data pin voltages" you can see how to tell your device it can draw more current.  The proper method though would be to use a controller IC something like TI's TPS2511 "USB Dedicated Charging Port Controller and Current Limiting Power Switch".  Hope this helps and isn't too too late.